# @BeforeClass and @AfterClass in Xcode XCTests

Tags: xcode, testing, xctest

In JUnit testing, there is a notion of being able to run code before or after the tests run. All I see in Xcode, however, is -setUp and -tearDown, which happen before and after every test.

Is there an Xcode equivalent to @BeforeClass and @AfterClass in JUnit?

Comment: there is no equivalent of JUnit's "BeforeClass" and "AfterClass" as of XCode 11.4

Answer (score 3):

There are following methods provided by **XCTestCase** which runs before and after any test in the test class is executed:

```
+ (void)setUp;
```

> Setup method called before the invocation of any test method in the
>   class.

```
+ (void)tearDown;
```

> Teardown method called after the invocation of every test method in
>   the class.